# Interceptor per api in retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I have four different apis and each one of them has its own headers.
I tried using the interceptor mechanism for filling the headers, instead of giving each call the same headers but since OkHttp interceptor runs for each and every request, i cannot make an interceptor per api.

I didn't find any other mechanism in Retrofit2 that would allow me to avoid writing the same headers for each and every request.

What would be a good way to give bunch of calls same headers?

Comment: you can give okhttp the interceptor and add the okclient to the retrofit builder

Comment: I need to configure few different okhttp clients since each retrofit api has different interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem. I needed to add Cache Headers to the responses received on the basis of the API.

To solve this problem, I used an interceptor that can evaluate the URL of the response and depending on that add/remove the Cache Headers.

For your problem the interceptor would be something like this,

```
public class HeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        HttpUrl url = request.url();

        // Add headers depending upon the url
        // Proceed the request
    }
}
```

Add this interceptor to your OkHttp client, and it will add particular headers to a set of calls.

Hope it helps.